# Abstract Angular Directive not providing services

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I don't understand why this does nothing

```js
@Directive({
  providers: [CalendarComponentStateService]
})
export abstract class AbstractEventsComponent {

  calendarMonthEventsStateService = inject(CalendarComponentStateService);
```

Other than throw

> NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(EmployeeHubModule)[CalendarComponentStateService ->
> CalendarComponentStateService -> CalendarComponentStateService ->
> CalendarComponentStateService]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for
> CalendarComponentStateService!

I am required to provide in the concrete component class, which i don't really like.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-events-calendar',
  templateUrl: './events-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events-calendar.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [CalendarComponentStateService]
})
export class EventsCalendarComponent extends AbstractEventsComponent {}
```